# Laravel queued job creating notifications

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I have a job queue that is triggered when an site admin uploads a new video:

```
SendVideoNotifications::dispatch($video)
```

which will send hundreds or thousands of queued notifications like so:

```
$users = User::where('active', true);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $notification = new VideoUploaded($this->video);

    $user->notify($notification);
}
```

Ocassionally and seemingly randomly, I'll get a queue timeout

```
App\Notifications\VideoUploaded has been attempted too many times or run too long. 
The job may have previously timed out.
```

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275080/12375621 seems to suggest that the architecture of queueing both the job and notifications is unstable, but I'm not sure if I can queue thousands of emails quickly enough before PHP eventually times out.

Is anyone else experiencing this? How can I change the architecture to accomplish what I'd like?

Comment: Seems some of your `VideoUploaded` notifications are repeatedly failing or timing out during execution.Try implementing the `failed` method, to determine reason why job is failing - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs

Comment: I've implemented the ```failed``` method which gives me the error in the post: ```App\Notifications\VideoUploaded has been attempted too many times or run too long. 
The job may have previously timed out.```